# Rscript - get rid of "WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME"

Tags: r, rscript

Rscript is very handy. But I'd like to specify output paths at runtime, e.g.: `my.Rscript  input > output`. 
`message()` is great for logging to STDERR, but Rscript seems to systematically output `WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME` to STDOUT, even if specifying `--vanilla` or `--no-environ`.

Any workarounds?

(this is R scripting front-end version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13))

Comment: What if you don't *want* it to ignore `R_HOME`? I get this error message when I run `R RHOME`, and it's using `/usr/lib/R` instead of `/home/mohawkjohn/R` (which I specified in my `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 6):

i assume this is very old.  but, with bash, etc.:

```
unset R_HOME
```

before running Rscript should do the trick.  and, with csh, etc.:

```
unsetenv R_HOME
```

should likewise work.  since the R front-end script sets R_HOME (after complaining), i don't see any reason for leaving R_HOME set.  (possibly i'm missing something.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know which R call in the script is generating the warning, `suppressWarnings()` can be used to wrap the expression generating the warning. That is certainly in the "workaround" camp.

Comment: I filed bug 15070 about this. https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15070